# How to refresh my UIViewController with new data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary, uialertview

Here's a `ChatViewController.m` that receives message which is then displayed in a `tableView`.
Now when the sender of message changes , I want to give option to the user to switch to the new message ( `alert view` ) . If the user clicks switch , how to display the message?

This is how the message is received and displayed.

```
 -(void)recvdMsg:(NSDictionary *)msg
{
  NSString *currentUser = [msg objectForKey:@"sender"];
  NSString *match = @"@";
  NSString *preAt ;
  NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:currentUser];
  [scanner scanUpToString:match intoString:&preAt];

  if (self.name == preAt)  //same sender 
  {
    NSMutableDictionary *newMsg=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    NSString *m = [msg objectForKey:@"msg"];
   [newMsg setObject:m forKey:@"message"];
   [newMsg setObject:converID forKey:@"conversationID"];
   [newMsg setObject:@"1" forKey:@"FromTo"];
   NSDate *today=[NSDate date];

   // Convert string to date object
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
   NSString *dt=[dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
   [newMsg setObject:dt forKey:@"timeStamp"];
   [self AddMessage:newMsg]; // adding to database.
   NSBubbleData *heyBubble = [NSBubbleData dataWithText:m date:[NSDate date] type:BubbleTypeSomeoneElse];
   [bubbleData addObject:heyBubble];
   [bbltblView reloadData];
   [bbltblView scrollBubbleViewToBottomAnimated:YES];
}
else     //message from new sender
{   
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"New Message from " message:preAt delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Switch", nil];
}

}

 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)  // cancel button clicked
{
    return;
}
else {

    // switch button is clicked....How to go from here.....how would i reload data?
}
}
```

Comment: Use `[tableview reloadData];`. after updating your datasource

Comment: Here in case of new user if you want to display messages from new user only then on alert switch code remove all objects from bubbleData and add message of new user only, if you want data from all users in bubbleData but just want to display messages then apply predicate on bubbleData on key "sender" and use filtered array to display data in tableview, don't forget to call reloadData for tableview.

Comment: Can you help with some sample code please.

Answer (score 1):

you can implement alertview delegate metnod as below

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) //OK Button
    {
       //ok button code
    }
    else //Switch Button
    {
        //switch button code
        [tableview reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think [tableview reloadData] would give me anything in my case, since i am giving data to table view in if statement above and in else stmt i am showing alert view.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement alertView delegate

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if(buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
         // Switch action, Write your logic to reload you data
    }
  }
```

Comment: So far , I know how to display alert view, and get users action of which button is clicked, the problem is how to display the data ..

Comment: You can use same code here which you used to load the data of current chat buddy.

Comment: So I would need to copy the message in a dictionary property for using it in another method i guess..

Comment: I have no idea how you are doing. You can apply same approch here to load new buddy messages in table.

Comment: I am receiving message in a dictionary , like I have posted above, If I want to use this in a method of alert view delegate ...I would need a copy of that , that's what I think....Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

Well same thing you need to follow in your `else` condition as well which you have done in your above `if` condiiton. Means again you have to `refresh` your `array` and then again you need to `reload` your `tableview` for populating new data like this below:-

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) //OK Button
    {
       //ok button code
    }
    else //Switch Button
    {
        // when switch button is clicked....write below for reloading the data
   [bubbleData addObject:heyBubble];// here heyBubble will be your new data
     [bbltblView reloadData];
    }
}
```